# Finding an Osculating Circle

Tags: calculus, circles, osculating-circle

I am working on a problem with the following directions:

> Find the osculating circle at the given points: $r(t)=<t,t^3> at $t=1$.

This image is my work so far. I cannot figure out how to find the center of my circle. I know it is the radius units in the direction of N, but how do I figure that out?

[image]

Comment: @amd sorry - the question was in there, but for some reason, it wasn't showing up.

Comment: In the future, please include your work as text instead of pasting a picture of it—images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a quick reference to MathJax, which is used for formatting mathematical expressions here.

Comment: Hint: the Frenet frame unit normal $N$ points in the direction of curvature. Or you could graph the function and see on which side the osculating circle must lie.

Comment: @amd I know that. But how do I travel the right number of units in the direction of the Normal vector when the normal vector is at an angle?

Comment: Then what’s the problem? Why should it matter that it’s “at an angle?” It’s a _unit_ vector, so just multiply it by the distance to be traveled. If you’re obtainig it from the coefficients of the tangent line equation, then normalize it.